# limit of $\frac{x}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

What is $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{x^{2}}$  ?

I have not tried anything as I flat don't know the answer
I Googled but could not find and answer
Pretty sure the limit of $\frac{1}{x}$ is zero but I don't know if that is the same as  $\frac{x}{x^{2}}$ with limits

The acutual question is gravity
$\frac{m1 m2}{r^{2}}$
As m2 and r approach infinity

In x y

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty y\to \infty}\frac{y}{x^{2}}$  ?

x y have no specific relationship

The theoretical is max acceleration a human body could sustain under a high gravity
You just make m2 infinitely big and infinite acceleration
My argument is tidal forces would pull the body apart
If you were getting sucked into a black hole you would get elongated as you approached the black hole
The front side of the body has different r than the back
The other party is saying no you just make r (x) big (infinite) so the tidal force goes to zero
My argument is if x and y go to infinity the force goes to zero - you cannot eliminate tidal force - you must take a finite y and let x increase toward infinity

Am I correct?  If x and y approach infinity does the force of gravity go to zero.  But x and y have no specific relationship (that I am aware of).

Comment: you want the limits of $\frac{x}{x^2}$?

Comment: Yes, how did you do that?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Click edit on your question to see the code to how it is done.

Comment: For $x\ne 0$, what is $x/x^2$?

Comment: @Dr.MV 1/x but I am just not sure if you if it works that way.  The actual question is gravity m1 X m2  /  (r x r).  As m2 and r approach infinity.  Sorry I have not yet learned the notation.

Comment: A new user gets a -1 for that.  You are guys are brutal.   But, hey I am the one asking for help.

Comment: @Frisbee I gave a +1 to annihilate the down vote that someone else gave as I abhor down voting.   Now that you clarified, your problem is actually of the form $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)}\frac{x}{y^2}$$One would need more information to evaluate such a limit. If $x$ and $y$ have no defined relationship, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Dr.MV Then this gets complex.  I will add to the question but maybe it should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim that the limit is zero. If $x > 0$, then
$$
\frac{x}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{x};
$$
given any $\varepsilon > 0$,
we have $1/x < \varepsilon$ if $x > 1/\varepsilon$.
We have proved that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $x > 1/\varepsilon$ implying $1/x < \varepsilon$; hence
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x^{2}} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of seeing it. The easiest way is to just reduce it algebraically.

$$\frac{x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x}$$

so now it's reduced to the situation with which you are familiar. Note that the above can be done because we're interested in the end behavior of the function so there is no concern about $x$ being near zero.